# follow user on twitter using twitter API

Tags: jquery, twitter

I am using following code to follow on twitter

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >

    function followFrd(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json',
            data: {screen_name: 'userName',follow: true},
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            timeout: '5000',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    $('#fllw').append(""+xhr.status);
                    $('#fllw').append(""+thrownError);
                    $('#fllw').append(""+ajaxOptions);
                }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
<div id="fllw">

</div>
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="followFrd()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting timeout in this case.

Do I need to use any authentication mechanism?? If yes than please guide me how to use that because I am new to twitter api.

**PS: I want to use javaScript or jQuery.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need authentication especially with API v1.1. You can use existing libraries to do this for you such as: https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient